# Using Stack Allocation instead of Heap allocation for factory methods

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, heap-memory, stack-memory

I am trying to refactor some code. Currently that code follows pattern like :

```
function f() {
Transaction trans;
// Do Operation
trans.commit();
}
```

Here transaction is concrete class. I want to move it to Interface and make this code look like as:

```
function f() {
ITransaction* trans = GetTransaction();
// Do Operation
trans->commit();
}

// Factory 
ITransaction* GetTransaction()
{
return new Transaction();
}
```

PROBLEM: we started using new here in factory method, which make heap allocation now. I want to avoid such heap allocation and still manage to use Interface. 
Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Kailas

Comment: A custom allocator should resolve most if not all of your performance concerns. I'd also suggest using `std::unique_ptr` so your example doesn't leak.

Comment: "I want to avoid such heap allocation" - Which aspect of heap allocation is bothering you?

Comment: If the number of transaction types is fixed, look into *variant* types, e.g. `boost::variant`.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is something like a allocate the Factory class on stack.

```
void function() {
    Factory factory{};
    auto transaction = factory.getTransaction(arguments...);
}
```

Factory can look like:

```
class Factory {
    A aTransaction;
    B bTransaction;
    C correctTransaction;

    transactionBase* getTransaction(arguments...) { 
        //return one member based on arguments
    }
}
```

However, if your arguments allow for templates, it becomes a bit easier to do something like

```
void function () {
    Factory<Arguments...> transaction;
}
```